# question about ? and : in c++

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

Why this statement :

```
int a = 7, b = 8, c = 0;
c = b>a?a>b?a++:b++:a++?b++:a--;
cout << c;
```

is not equal to :

```
int a = 7, b = 8, c = 0;
c = (b>a?(a>b?a++:b++):a++)?b++:a--;
cout << c;
```

and is equal to :

```
int a = 7, b = 8, c = 0;
c = b>a?(a>b?a++:b++):(a++?b++:a--);
cout << c;
```

Please give me some reason. Why ?

Comment: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence

Comment: Jesus Christ, why would you ever want to write code like that?!

Comment: You should write the code nicely with brackets unless you know the precedences

Comment: s/unless you know the precedences//.  This code would be a pain for anyone to understand, even someone intimately familiar with precedence, associativity, and all that.  Better to split it into multiple lines and use if statements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `? :` is right-to-left associative. It's defined like that in the language.

Comment: You know, I think you're right and I'm wrong.  I'm going to delete mine.

Answer (score 7):

I believe @sth has provided the correct answer, however, I think @Skilldrick got it right on the comments - why the hell would you ever write something like that.

As well as the precedence issue, you really need to be careful when incrementing the same variables in a single statement.  There may or may not be sequence points in the statement, and therefore the order of evaluation of the increments might not be guaranteed.  You could end up with different results with different compilers or even different optimization settings on the same compiler.

Comment: Absolutely - multiple increments of the same variable at the same sequence point is the dreaded *undefined behaviour*. That line could probably legally be equal to either of those.

Comment: The order of a ? b : c is guaranteed.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but isn't `?:` one of those operators who does guarantee the order of evaluation and does have sequence points between evaluating operands (others are `,`, `&&`, `||` and perhaps some others)?

Comment: Isn't the real answer to this question phimuemue's one on operator precedence? There's no code branch in this where or b are incremented twice is there?

Comment: @Neil, is the greediness of the matching of ? with : defined?  I thought that was one of those "why the hell would you do that" sort of things.

Comment: @Skilldrick, I think the real answer is yours.

Comment: @Paul Eh? I didn't mention "greediness".

Comment: @Neil, no you didn't, but is it defined how if you have `? ? : :` which way they associate?  @sth says it is in his answer.  I didn't know that.

Comment: @Paul Associativity is defined for all C++ operators.

Answer (score 1):

The operators `&&`, `||`, and `?:` perform flow control within expressions. `?:` behaves like an if-else statement.

```
c = b>a?a>b?a++:b++:a++?b++:a--;

if ( b>a )
    if ( a>b )
        a ++;
    else
        b ++;
else if ( a ++ )
    b ++;
else
    a --;

b>a? (
    a>b ?
        a ++
    :
        b ++
) : ( a ++ ?
    b ++
:
    a --
)
```

The associativity is necessary to have behavior like `if … else if … else`.

Sometimes I use an expression similar to yours for lexicographic sequence comparision:

```
operator< ()( arr &l, arr &r ) {
    return l[0] < r[0]? true
         : r[0] < l[0]? false
         : l[1] < r[1]? true
         : r[1] < l[1]? false
         : l[2] < r[2];
}
```